# Displaying Text for One Frame in Python

Tags: python, wxpython

Is there a way to build a python program that can display a word or picture on the computer screen for only one frame?

Stated differently, my monitor refreshes at 60 Hz.  I want to display a text or picture on the screen for only 1/60 of a second.

Specifically, I am running on Windows 7 with python 2.7.  An answer using wxpython would be preferred, but any answer with any platform or operating system would be appreciated.

Is there a way to allow me to display text on screen for a specific number of frames?

Right now I have

```
refresh_rate = 60.0  # Screen refreshes at 60 Hz
time_of_single_frame = 1.0 / refresh_rate
text = wx.StaticText(self, label='Text to Show')
t = time.time()
while time.time() - t < time_of_single_frame:  # waiting for one frame to pass
    pass
text.Hide()
```

However, I do not believe this gives the behavior that I want due to latencies and imprecision in the time it takes to show and hide the text. Is there a way to be more precise in this timing?  Additionally, is there a way to show and hide my stimulus based on the number of frames that have passed instead of measuring time?  I am under the assumption that this would allow for even greater precision.

Comment: Thank you.  I made a correction to what I had written so it is more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As is, your question is off-topic because of "Edit: Is there a python library that would..." "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thank you.  That was only a subset of my question.  I revised it accordingly.